# How do you remove/suppress the "Enter Your Adobe ID" popup that comes with CS5.5?

Tags: macos, adobe-acrobat

When launching a CS5.5 application or Acrobat X this window sometimes pops up.  I can't seem to find a preference file that relates to it.  My google-fu doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: Did you obtain the software legally?

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way i found to get rid of the Adobe ID popup is to put the following lines into your `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file.

Open the hosts file as Administrator and copy/paste these lines into it then reboot your computer:

```
# Block Adobe Activation
127.0.0.1 hl2rcv.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 t3dns.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-1.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sea.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sjc0.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip1.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-1.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ood.opsource.net
127.0.0.1 209-34-83-73.ood.opsource.net
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 tpractivate.adobe.newoa
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.ntp
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.ipp
127.0.0.1 ereg.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip1.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip1.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 www.wip.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 www.wip1.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 www.wip2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 www.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 www.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip60.adobe.com

#Block Adobe CS4 Activation Server
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobeereg.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sea.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip60.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sjc0.adobe.com

#Block Adobe CS5 Activation Server
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 3dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-2.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip3.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sea.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip60.adobe.com
127.0.0.1 activate-sjc0.adobe.com

# Block Adobe Acrobat X Pro 10.0 Activation Server
127.0.0.1 3dns-2.adobe.com #192.150.22.22
127.0.0.1 3dns-3.adobe.com #192.150.14.21
127.0.0.1 3dns-4.adobe.com #192.150.18.247
127.0.0.1 3dns-5.adobe.com #192.150.22.46
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns.adobe.com #192.150.11.30
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-2.adobe.com #192.150.11.247
127.0.0.1 adobe-dns-3.adobe.com #192.150.22.30
127.0.0.1 adobe.activate.com #69.175.22.26
127.0.0.1 activate.adobe.com #192.150.22.40
127.0.0.1 activate.wip3.adobe.com #192.150.22.40
127.0.0.1 activate.wip4.adobe.com #192.150.22.40
127.0.0.1 activate-sea.adobe.com #192.150.22.40
127.0.0.1 activate-sjc0.adobe.com #192.150.14.69
127.0.0.1 ereg.adobe.com #192.150.18.103
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip3.adobe.com #192.150.18.63
127.0.0.1 ereg.wip4.adobe.com #192.150.18.103
127.0.0.1 practivate.adobe.com #192.150.18.54
127.0.0.1 www.wip3.adobe.com #192.150.8.60
127.0.0.1 www.wip4.adobe.com #192.150.18.200
127.0.0.1 www.adobeereg.com #75.125.24.83
127.0.0.1 adobeereg.com #207.66.2.10
127.0.0.1 hl2rcv.adobe.com #192.150.14.174
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip30.adobe.com #192.150.8.30
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip31.adobe.com #192.150.8.31
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip32.adobe.com #192.150.8.32
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip33.adobe.com #192.150.8.33
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip34.adobe.com #192.150.8.34
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip35.adobe.com #192.150.8.35
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip36.adobe.com #192.150.8.36
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip37.adobe.com #192.150.8.37
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip38.adobe.com #192.150.8.38
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip39.adobe.com #192.150.8.39
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip40.adobe.com #192.150.8.40
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip41.adobe.com #192.150.8.41
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip42.adobe.com #192.150.8.42
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip43.adobe.com #192.150.8.43
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip44.adobe.com #192.150.8.44
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip45.adobe.com #192.150.8.45
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip46.adobe.com #192.150.8.46
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip47.adobe.com #192.150.8.47
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip48.adobe.com #192.150.8.48
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip49.adobe.com #192.150.8.49
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip50.adobe.com #192.150.8.50
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip51.adobe.com #192.150.8.51
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip52.adobe.com #192.150.8.52
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip53.adobe.com #192.150.8.53
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip54.adobe.com #192.150.8.54
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip55.adobe.com #192.150.8.55
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip56.adobe.com #192.150.8.56
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip57.adobe.com #192.150.8.57
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip58.adobe.com #192.150.8.58
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip59.adobe.com #192.150.8.59
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip60.adobe.com #192.160.8.60
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip61.adobe.com #192.160.8.61
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip62.adobe.com #192.160.8.62
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip63.adobe.com #192.160.8.63
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip64.adobe.com #192.160.8.64
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip65.adobe.com #192.160.8.65
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip66.adobe.com #192.160.8.66
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip67.adobe.com #192.160.8.67
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip68.adobe.com #192.160.8.68
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip69.adobe.com #192.160.8.69
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip70.adobe.com #192.170.8.70
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip71.adobe.com #192.170.8.71
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip72.adobe.com #192.170.8.72
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip73.adobe.com #192.170.8.73
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip74.adobe.com #192.170.8.74
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip75.adobe.com #192.170.8.75
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip76.adobe.com #192.170.8.76
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip77.adobe.com #192.170.8.77
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip78.adobe.com #192.170.8.78
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip79.adobe.com #192.170.8.79
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip80.adobe.com #192.180.8.80
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip81.adobe.com #192.180.8.81
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip82.adobe.com #192.180.8.82
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip83.adobe.com #192.180.8.83
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip84.adobe.com #192.180.8.84
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip85.adobe.com #192.180.8.85
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip86.adobe.com #192.180.8.86
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip87.adobe.com #192.180.8.87
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip88.adobe.com #192.180.8.88
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip89.adobe.com #192.180.8.89
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip90.adobe.com #192.190.8.90
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip91.adobe.com #192.190.8.91
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip92.adobe.com #192.190.8.92
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip93.adobe.com #192.190.8.93
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip94.adobe.com #192.190.8.94
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip95.adobe.com #192.190.8.95
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip96.adobe.com #192.190.8.96
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip97.adobe.com #192.190.8.97
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip98.adobe.com #192.190.8.98
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip99.adobe.com #192.190.8.99
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip100.adobe.com #192.1100.8.100
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip101.adobe.com #192.1100.8.101
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip102.adobe.com #192.1100.8.102
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip103.adobe.com #192.1100.8.103
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip104.adobe.com #192.1100.8.104
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip105.adobe.com #192.1100.8.105
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip106.adobe.com #192.1100.8.106
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip107.adobe.com #192.1100.8.107
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip108.adobe.com #192.1100.8.108
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip109.adobe.com #192.1100.8.109
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip110.adobe.com #192.1110.8.110
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip111.adobe.com #192.1110.8.111
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip112.adobe.com #192.1110.8.112
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip113.adobe.com #192.1110.8.113
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip114.adobe.com #192.1110.8.114
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip115.adobe.com #192.1110.8.115
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip116.adobe.com #192.1110.8.116
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip117.adobe.com #192.1110.8.117
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip118.adobe.com #192.1110.8.118
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip119.adobe.com #192.1110.8.119
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip120.adobe.com #192.1120.8.120
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip121.adobe.com #192.1120.8.121
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip122.adobe.com #192.1120.8.122
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip123.adobe.com #192.1120.8.123
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip124.adobe.com #192.1120.8.124
127.0.0.1 wwis-dubc1-vip125.adobe.com #192.1120.8.125
```

Comment: I suspect that his mac does not have that file.